# Java generalize approach to validate the null in the object parameters

Tags: java, list, dictionary, for-loop, java-8

I am trying to implement a logic where I have a POJO class which has 7 attributes. 
I have added these POJO classes into the map depends upon the value of the attributes.

Below is the implementation

```
Map<String,List<PriceClass>> map = new HashMap();
for (PriceClass price : prices) {
  if (price.getAttribute1() !=null) {
      if (map.get("attribute1") !=null) {
             map.get("attribute1").add(price);
      } else {
           map.set("attibute1",Collections.singletonList(price))
      }
   } else if(price.getAttribute2()!=null) {
       if (map.get("attribute12") !=null) {
             map.get("attribute2").add(price);
       } else {
           map.set("attibute2",Collections.singletonList(price))
       }
   } else if (price.getAttribute3() !=null) {
     .
     .
     .
   } else if (price.getAttribute7() !=null) {
       //update the map
   }
}
```

My question is rather than writing these many if loops are there any generalize implementations I can try here.

Comment: Have you tried to use streams here?

Comment: I would use Guava's [Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) instead of a home-baked one. What are you actually trying to accomplish besides `null` checking?

Comment: Have you tried computeIfAbsent ? it is basically what you just made yourself

Comment: so, if all elements inside list `prices` has `attribute1` , then the output map will contain only 1 element with key as `attribute1` and `prices` list as the value?

Comment: because in your if-else chain, it will not go inside other `if`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likely optimal solution would be similar to **[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891083/refactor-multiple-if-statements-in-java-8/51891414#51891414)** I have suggested earlier today.

Use the `Map<String, Optional<?>>` to store the `Optional` values of the checked attributes with a key of the future output map key.

```
Map<String, Optional<?>> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put("attribute1", Optional.ofNullable(price.getAttribute1()));
// ...
options.put("attribute3", Optional.ofNullable(price.getAttribute2()));
// ...
```

Using the iteration of the indices would let you perform the update of a map.

```
Map<String,List<Price>> map = new HashMap();
for (int i=1; i<7; i++) {                                      // attributes 1..7
    String attribute = "attribute" + i;                        // attribute1...attribute7
    options.get(attribute).ifPresent(any ->                    // for non-nulls
               map.put(                                        // put to the map
                   attribute,                                  // attribute as key remains
                   Optional.ofNullable(map.get(attribute))     // gets the existing list
                           .orElse(new ArrayList<>())          // or creates empty
                           .add(price)));                      // adds the current Price
}
```

Moreover, I bet your intention was a bit different. There is no method `Map::set`

```
map.set("attibute1",Collections.singletonList(price))
```

Didn't you mean to put a `List<Price>` with one item to the very same key instead?

```
map.put("attibute1", Collections.singletonList(price))
```

For this reason you can use the way I posted above.

Comment: Overuse of `Optional`. Just use `map.computeIfAbsent(attribute, x -> new ArrayList<>()) .add(price)` to create an `ArrayList` when needed and add an element. It’s simpler and even more efficient, as it only needs a single map lookup.

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
Map<String,List<PriceClass>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(PriceClass price: prices) {
    HashMap<String,Object> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("attibute1", price.getAttribute1());
    options.put("attibute2", price.getAttribute2());
    options.put("attibute3", price.getAttribute3());
    options.put("attibute4", price.getAttribute4());
    options.put("attibute5", price.getAttribute5());
    options.put("attibute6", price.getAttribute6());
    options.put("attibute7", price.getAttribute7());
    options.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
    options.keySet().forEach(attr -> map.computeIfAbsent(attr, x -> new ArrayList<>())
                                        .add(price));
}
```

or generalizing the process:

Prepare a unmodifiable map once

```
static final Map<String, Function<PriceClass,Object>> ATTR;
static {
  Map<String, Function<PriceClass,Object>> a = new HashMap<>();
  a.put("attibute1", PriceClass::getAttribute1);
  a.put("attibute2", PriceClass::getAttribute2);
  a.put("attibute3", PriceClass::getAttribute3);
  a.put("attibute4", PriceClass::getAttribute4);
  a.put("attibute5", PriceClass::getAttribute5);
  a.put("attibute6", PriceClass::getAttribute6);
  a.put("attibute7", PriceClass::getAttribute7);
  ATTR = Collections.unmodifiableMap(a);
}
```

and use either

```
Map<String,List<PriceClass>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(PriceClass price: prices) {
    HashMap<String,Object> options = new HashMap<>();
    ATTR.forEach((attr,func) -> options.put(attr, func.apply(price)));
    options.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
    options.keySet().forEach(attr -> map.computeIfAbsent(attr, x -> new ArrayList<>())
                                        .add(price));
}
```

or

```
Map<String,List<PriceClass>> map = prices.stream()
    .flatMap(price -> ATTR.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().apply(price) != null)
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), price)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: I've read all the answer when the question was posted and said that's about it, I can't add more. But this, damn, so simple, yet, so nice!

Answer (score 1):

What about using e.g. `Enum` to define 7 different objects each of them is responsible for concrete attribute:

```
// this is client code, looks pretty easy
Map<String, List<PriceClass>> map = new HashMap<>();

for (PriceClass price : prices)
    PriceAttribute.add(map, price);


// all logic is hidden within special Enum    
enum PriceAttribute {
    ATTRIBUTE1("attribute1", PriceClass::getAttribute1),
    ATTRIBUTE2("attribute2", PriceClass::getAttribute2),
    ATTRIBUTE3("attribute3", PriceClass::getAttribute3),
    ATTRIBUTE4("attribute4", PriceClass::getAttribute4),
    ATTRIBUTE5("attribute5", PriceClass::getAttribute5),
    ATTRIBUTE6("attribute6", PriceClass::getAttribute6),
    ATTRIBUTE7("attribute7", PriceClass::getAttribute7);

    private final String key;
    private final Function<PriceClass, ?> get;

    PriceAttribute(String key, Function<PriceClass, ?> get) {
        this.key = key;
        this.get = get;
    }

    public static void add(Map<String, List<PriceClass>> map, PriceClass price) {
        for (PriceAttribute attribute : values()) {
            if (attribute.get.apply(price) != null) {
                map.computeIfAbsent(attribute.key, key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(price);    
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Likely a good solution. However, since Java-8 and `Optional` I tend to avoid these `null` checks.

Comment: @Nikolas Fixed, but I do not hesitate to use plain old `null` instead of `Optional` depending on situation.

Comment: Also `Optional.ofNullable(data).orElse(new ArrayList<>()).add(price);`. Agreed that "depending on situation", as you have said. Deserved +1.

Comment: @Nikolas Thank. This is almost correct for Optional. I have modified. P.S. for new list you do not have reference then.

Comment: A cleaner way to add to the Map would be `map.computeIfAbsent(attribute.key, k -> new ArrayList<PriceClass>()).add(price);`.

Answer (score 0):

Following is repetitive code:

```
       if(map.get("attribute1") !=null)
         {
             map.get("attribute1").add(price);
          }
        else
         {
           map.set("attibute1",Collections.singletonList(price))
          }
```

It could be refactored into a method, and called from the parent method which could make this look a bit cleaner.

Additionally you can also try

prices.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)) and then run loop through it, to avoid one "If" condition.

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet can be added as a method.

```
if(map.get("attribute1") !=null) {
  map.get("attribute1").add(price);
} else {
  map.set("attibute1",Collections.singletonList(price))
}
```

to

```
private static void addPrice(String attributeName, Price price){
    if(map.get(attributeName) !=null) {
      map.get(attributeName).add(price);
    } else {
      map.set(attributeName,Collections.singletonList(price))
    }
}
```

Also, map should be created static to be used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

That wasn't be strict answer to the question but I want to improve your code.

You call `get` twice. Instead of this:

```
if(map.get("attribute1") !=null) {
  map.get("attribute1").add(price);
} else {
  map.set("attibute1",Collections.singletonList(price))
}
```

Use this:

```
final List<PriceClass> attribute1 = map.get("attribute1");
if (attribute1 != null) {
    attribute1.add(price);
} else {
    map.set("attibute1", Collections.singletonList(price))
}
```

---

Second you use `Collections.singletonList` which create immutable list so if you try to add something to it (and you do it) you'll get exception. You should use

`new ArrayList<PriceClass>(Arrays.asList(price))` or

`Stream.of(price).collect(toList())`

Comment: thanks for the reply.My main concern is the if condition where we are checking null for each of the attribute not about the map.Any inputs related to it

Answer (score 0):

If this is the real code you have, so create an array of attribute

```
Attribute[] attributesOf(Price price){
    Attribute[] a = new Attribute[7];
    a[0] = price.getAttribute1();
    a[1] = price.getAttribute2();
    ...
    a[6] = price.getAttribute7();
}
```

when you have more attributes, just modify this method. Then your code can be refactor to

```
for(PriceClass price : prices){
    Attribute[] attributes = attributesOf(price);
    for(int i=0;i<attributes.length;i++){
    String key = "attribute" + (i+1);
        if(attributes[i] != null){
            map.get(key).add(price);
        }
        else{
            map.set(key, Collections.singletonList(price));
        }
    }
}
```

But if you code are different, like price.getGrossAmount(), price.getNetAmount(), price.getTax() you have to find the general contract to define the type of array.

Nevertheless, you have to understand that good data structure will make your code simple and perform well. Maybe you don't need to define attribute in the price class. Maybe you don't need the price class, but you can use BigDecimal as the price value instead.

I don't know your context well, I don't know what are you doing. I think you might have a better answer from someone else if you show the real code as well as its context.

Answer (score 0):

Acc. to your question, it seems like if `attibute1` is present in a `PriceClass` object, it will go to the `attibute1` key. This means if all objects in `prices` list has `attibute1`, the whole list will go the `attibute1` key.

With the above assumption, here is a java-8 solution containing streams.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<String,List<PriceClass>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<PriceClass> prices =new ArrayList<>();
    prices.add(new PriceClass(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
    prices.add(new PriceClass(null,12,13,14,15,16,17));
    map = prices.stream()
            .map(priceClass -> Arrays
                    .stream(PriceClass.class.getDeclaredFields())
                    .map(field -> getFieldValue(field, priceClass))
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(null)
            )
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue,
                            Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(map);
}

private static AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,PriceClass> getFieldValue(Field field, PriceClass priceClass){
    Optional<Integer> value = Optional.empty();
    try {
        value = Optional.ofNullable((Integer)field.get(priceClass));
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (value.isPresent()) {
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(field.getName(), priceClass);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Output:

```
{attribute1=[PriceClass{attribute1=1, attribute2=2, attribute3=3, attribute4=4, attribute5=5, attribute6=6, attribute7=7}], 

 attribute2=[PriceClass{attribute1=null, attribute2=12, attribute3=13, attribute4=14, attribute5=15, attribute6=16, attribute7=17}]}
```